# Display a String variable on screen

Tags: java, android

I am building a object detection APP. I want to display the String variable `speed` on screen.

I tried using `TextView` but the variable is not in `MainActivity.java`.
It is in `tracking/MultiBoxTracker.java`

```java
public class MultiBoxTracker {
...
 public synchronized void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
...
final String labelString =                    
          !TextUtils.isEmpty(recognition.title)
              ? String.format("%s %.2f", recognition.title, (100 * recognition.detectionConfidence))
              : String.format("%.2f", (100 * recognition.detectionConfidence));
      //            borderedText.drawText(canvas, trackedPos.left + cornerSize, trackedPos.top,
      // labelString);

      String speed = recognition.title; //TODO Display it on the screen.
...
}
```

`String speed = recognition.title` is the String variable.
I want it to show on the screen ([.xml View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZQUB.png))
and change as the program runs.

Thank you very much.

Comment: and what is the actual question?

Comment: You can use broadcast receiver or interface/callback for this.

Comment: I want the String variable speed to display on the screen.